# EditText Autofill bug on Android 10

Tags: android, android-edittext, autofill

After I selected/clicked on EditText field, my app have crashed. Nothing special, it's a simple EditText without any style or something. Logs says that this crash occurred in AutofillManager.java. From this information I guess it's some kind of android 10 issue with editText's autoFill. But why?

Logcat:

```
    at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.waitResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:60)
    at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.getIntResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:68)
    at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked(AutofillManager.java:1847)
    at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEnteredLocked(AutofillManager.java:966)
    at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered(AutofillManager.java:950)
    at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered(AutofillManager.java:901)
    at android.view.View.notifyEnterOrExitForAutoFillIfNeeded(View.java:7897)
    at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:7859)
    at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:10852)
    at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:7522)
    at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:12498)
    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:12472)
    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:12439)
    at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:12381)
    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:14899)
    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10911)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13490)
```

Comment: Please copy whole stack trace

Comment: This is the whole stack trace :/

Comment: No it is not full yet

Answer (score 5):

Anyway if we disable autofill it give us a temporary solution for crash.

```
android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: @Override
 public int getAutofillType() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
   return AUTOFILL_TYPE_NONE;
  } else {
   return super.getAutofillType();
  }
 }